# How to detect the specific coordinate points from array of points given by corner detection?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I have an image of a person head from which I detected the corner points. Here are my code and result from it:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

Head = cv2.imread('Head.jpg')

#Corner detection
gray = cv2.cvtColor(Head, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray  = np.float32(gray)

corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(gray, 50, 0.01, 10)
corners = np.int0(corners)

for corner in corners:
    x,y = corner.ravel()
    cv2.circle(Head, (x,y), 3, 255, -1)

z = np.max(y)
cv2.circle(Head, (x,z), 5, (0,0,255), -1)

cv2.imshow('Corner', Head)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Head Image:

[image: Head.jpg]

Corner Detected:

[image: Corner Points]

Here, I am trying to point out only two corners in neck area(Lowest ones in above image). For that, I find out the max y from numpy array of corners and plot the point in red point. But, its plotting red point in eye. What I am doing wrong?

How do I find out the coordinate points of neck(lowest 2 corner points only)??

Comment: What is the shape and dtype of corners?

Comment: What do you mean by shape of corners? If your are refering to image.shape, its 522 by 522. Dtype is unit8.

Comment: I'm referring to `corners = np.int0(corners)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in this line:

```
z = np.max(y)
```

Here the value of y will just be the value of the last corner looked at in the previous loop. What you can do is to create a list of all the coordinate of the corners, and then order the list based on the y value:

```
ordered_coords = [ corner.ravel() for corner in corners ]
ordered_coords.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

The two corners you're looking for with the highest y value will then be the last two elements in the list.

```
cv2.circle(Head, ordered_coords[-1], 5, (0,0,255), -1)
```

Comment: You're going to need to keep track of the *corresponding* x-coordinate

Comment: That is 100% true :p